# Create folder using PHP

Tags: php, file, directory

Can we create folder with PHP code? I want that whenever a new user create his new account his folder automatically creates and a PHP file also created. Is this possible?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: It is possible using `mkdir` - but what ever you are doing sounds 'wrong' in so many ways

Comment: 3) Triple threat=`mkdir` - Oops, mixed up Stevie in there. Now talk about "Double trouble" or what.

Comment: hehe thnx alot ...it solves all..now tell hoe to create php file with PHP code?

Comment: `fwrite()` with `w` switch

Comment: Come on man, you can Google this. It won't kill ya. Taxes will take care of that.

Comment: example plz? thnx in advance

Comment: @ShikhilBhalla [**fwrite( ) examples**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

Comment: @ShikhilBhalla [**mkdir ( ) example**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

Comment: hahahaha okei dokie @Fred

Comment: `<?php mkdir("testing"); ?>` <= this, actually creates a folder called "testing". Nobody even came close. C'mon people.

Comment: This is what came of when you google it.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

### Purely basic folder creation

`<?php mkdir("testing"); ?>` <= this, actually creates a folder called "testing".

- [**mkdir () function on PHP.net**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

---

---

### Basic file creation

```
<?php
$file = fopen("test.txt","w");
echo fwrite($file,"Hello World. Testing!");
fclose($file);
?>
```

Use the `a` or `a+` switch to add/append to file.

- [**fwrite() function on PHP.net**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

---

---

## EDIT:

#### This version will create a file and folder at the same time and show it on screen after.

```
<?php

// change the name below for the folder you want
$dir = "new_folder_name";

$file_to_write = 'test.txt';
$content_to_write = "The content";

if( is_dir($dir) === false )
{
    mkdir($dir);
}

$file = fopen($dir . '/' . $file_to_write,"w");

// a different way to write content into
// fwrite($file,"Hello World.");

fwrite($file, $content_to_write);

// closes the file
fclose($file);

// this will show the created file from the created folder on screen
include $dir . '/' . $file_to_write;

?>
```

Comment: ok done it creates the folder ,now how i can create file in that folder which is created by PHP code in a single file.

Comment: @ShikhilBhalla Exactly. Those are the pure basic examples of file and folder creation. More examples/options can be seen on PHP.net with the links I have provided for you. Cheers (*Peace*)

Answer (score 16):

You can create a directory with PHP using the [**mkdir()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) function.

`mkdir("/path/to/my/dir", 0700);`

You can use [**fopen()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) to create a file inside that directory with the use of the mode `w`.

`fopen('myfile.txt', 'w');`

> **w** : Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

Comment: thnx i solves all..can u tell me how to create file using PHP code?

Answer (score 6):

You can create it easily:

```
$structure = './depth1/depth2/depth3/';
if (!mkdir($structure, 0, true)) {
die('Failed to create folders...');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

... You can then use [`copy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) to duplicate a PHP file, although this sounds incredibly inefficient.

Comment: [**same thing**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216930/how-to-create-folder-with-php-code#comment26703107_18216960)

Comment: tell me the whole script with example.Thnx in advance

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the question in how to write to a file in PHP you can use the following as an example:

```
    $fp = fopen ($filename, "a"); # a = append to the file. w = write to the file (create new if doesn't exist)
    if ($fp) {
        fwrite ($fp, $text); //$text is what you are writing to the file
        fclose ($fp);
        $writeSuccess = "Yes";
        #echo ("File written");
    }
    else {
    $writeSuccess = "No";
    #echo ("File was not written");
    }
```