# How to create a directory based on a data in database and save the file in it

Tags: php, mysql

How can I create a directory that does not exist , based on a data in database and saves the file in it ?

example:

fName: Emrys

I would like to create a folder based on the fname and saves the file in it

Thanks.

Comment: @Fred-ii- any reference you can give is much help thank you :)

Comment: Dagon closed the question with a link you can reference. You can also consult one of my answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/18217147/1415724 - As for db-related; well, in a nutshell, you would need to use a `WHERE` clause for that, then use that reference for it to save the file with.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you very much :D

Comment: `include_once("../include/session.php");
$fname = $session->fname;
$directory = uploaded_files; 

if (!file_exists($directory."/".$fname)) {
mkdir($directory."/".$fname, 0777, true);
}` Sir @Fred-ii- How can I make it together with the last name?

Comment: @Fred-ii- got it now WORKING :D thanks for the BIG HELP :)