# Getting variables from a .txt file to execute a php program

Tags: python, php, linux

I've a situation in which I've to execute a PHP program by getting variables from each line of a .txt file.
To explain the situation here is an exampale:
The test file contains 3 lines and last word (numeric) is a variable-->

```
1. pqrs-->abc-->323
2. pqrs-->awqdx-->526
3. pqrs-->arc-->153
```

Now In PHP code, I want to import the 2nd parameter from each line of the .txt file and execute the code (sudo mkdir '2nd parameter from .txt file') one by one.
I tried to find its solution a lot but hard luck.
How to do this in Python, if not possible with PHP?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think that it's not possible in php?

Comment: A number cannot be a variable. Variable identifiers are not allowed to start with a digit.

Comment: @DYZ its just an example. To execute a program variable could be anything. isnt it?

Comment: @OlvinRoght I don't think so. I'm naive in coding so thought in python it could be easy

Comment: It is an unfortunate example because it is incorrect. Your question is already hard to understand; there is no reason ti make it even harder.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$myFile = "test.txt";
$lines = file($myFile);//file in to an array
foreach ($lines as $key => $line_each) {
    $data = explode('-->', $line_each);
    echo $data[2];
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. but it helps me only in separating the variables from the .txt file. I'm still not getting my program executed with those variables. for say:- my program is to make directories. im using   'sudo mkdir $data[2]' which doesn't create all the directories having same name as variables.

Comment: i think this is an another que to make dir in php.

Comment: Its not a new question. I want to execute a PHP program (for eg creating dir) which takes variables from another file and executes it with every variable at least once.

Comment: refer this..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216930/how-to-create-folder-with-php-code/18217147